# node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js error occur when build project asp.net core 2.0 with react.js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, react-router, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to create project in **asp.net core 2.0 with react.js**.
I have Visual Studio Community 2017 (2) version 15.9.17 with Microsoft .net framework v4.8.03761.
When I create project,  using  .Net Core > Asp.NET Core Web Application & select Asp.Net Core 2.0 as targeted version with React.js as showing in link https://www.screencast.com/t/SRVV7vOmkz
when I build project this error is showing

> Error MSB3073 The command  "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
>   --config webpack.config.vendor.js" exited with code 1.

Answer (score 1):

I could get a similar error info if I build a new project without running `npm i` when using `React` +`ASP.NET Core 2.0`.

If that's the case, please make sure

1. you have installed the `node.js`
2. run cmd/powershell (might require `RunAs Administrator` )
3. and `cd` into the project folder (the folder that contains the `*.csproj`)
4. run `npm i` to install the dependencies (**make sure there's no error info** when you run `npm i`.  If you cannot make it, try `npm i --force`):

```
> cd /path/to/the/folder/that/contains/the/*.proj/file
> npm i
```

Finally, it should work fine now.

---

As a side note, ASP.NET Core 2.0 has reached its EOL. Please consider updating it to 2.1 (LTS).

Comment: Is there need anything like webpack or node module to install manually?

Comment: @WaleedIrshad 1. For `ASP.NET Core 2.0`, you have to unless you change the `*.csproj`. If you don't like it, please **add a task** so that it runs `npm i`  automatically.   2. Or update to  higher version like `ASP.NET Core 3.0`. `ASP.NET Core 3.0` configures a task that executes `npm install` for you automatically.